# ubuntu 14.04, rpcbind stops machine from being rebooted

Tags: nfs, ubuntu-14.04, reboot, rpcbind

We have two servers, both running NFS shares. A while ago we upgraded them from 12.04 => 14.04, and ever since a clean reboot from the command-line has become all but impossible (well, we run into a timeout of some sort, I guess, but the reboot cycle takes > 8 minutes, which is highly undesirable).

They used to reboot fine (time taken for hardware checks & BIOS <3 minutes), but these days rpcbind sits there for what feels like forever.

How do I make that long wait go away again?

Comment: If you can, get rid of all NFSv3 or older.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - you mean try to replace it w/ nfsv4?

Comment: Yes, NFSv4 or later. v3 is a horrible nightmare, and v2 was even worse. NFSv4 is almost 20 years old now...

Comment: Well, there's that. But it was simple and quick to set-up. Will investigate. Do you know for sure that v4 would make that behaviour go away, or is that a general suggestion? ;}

Comment: I can't say for sure, or I would have posted an answer. But it's something you really should do anyway. NFSv4 isn't harder to set up than v3; it's _easier_. And it actually works better than v3. They removed a lot of unnecessary complexity (like portmap, etc).